# python-xarray: Changing dtypes when merging

Tags: python-xarray

I'm merging two datasets along an axis (in my case, `sample_ID`).  However, it seems the `dtype` for the databases converts from `int64` to `float64` even when the variable `dtype` was `int64` for both the first and second database.  My first database (`existing`) looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:          (sample_ID: 3)
Coordinates:
  * sample_ID  (sample_ID) int64 0 1 2
Data variables:
    a                (sample_ID) float64 1.0 2.0 1.1
    b                (sample_ID) float64 5.0 6.0 5.1
    varsUpdate       (sample_ID) int64 0 0 1
    y                (sample_ID) float64 100.0 200.0 100.1
    x                (sample_ID) float64 10.0 20.0 10.1
    trajID           (sample_ID) int64 1 2 1
```

The second database (`new`) looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:          (sample_ID: 1)
Coordinates:
  * sample_ID  (sample_ID) int64 3
Data variables:
    a                (sample_ID) float64 2.1
    b                (sample_ID) float64 6.1
    varsUpdate       (sample_ID) int64 1
    y                (sample_ID) float64 200.1
    x                (sample_ID) float64 20.1
    trajID           (sample_ID) int64 2
```

The final result after calling `existing.merge(new,inplace=True)` is

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:          (sample_ID: 4)
Coordinates:
  * sample_ID  (sample_ID) int64 0 1 2 3
Data variables:
    a                (sample_ID) float64 1.0 2.0 1.1 2.1
    b                (sample_ID) float64 5.0 6.0 5.1 6.1
    varsUpdate       (sample_ID) float64 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
    y                (sample_ID) float64 100.0 200.0 100.1 200.1
    x                (sample_ID) float64 10.0 20.0 10.1 20.1
    trajID           (sample_ID) float64 1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0
```

You can see that the types have all been converted to `float64`.  Is there an efficient way to maintain the integer types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xarray.merge(...)` combines datasets in a two stage process:

1. It calls `xarray.align(..., join='outer')` on the datasets to align their coordinates. This introduces NaNs, so we need to promote int64 -> float64.
2. It creates the merged dataset, as the single non-NaN value from the aligned datasets at each array position.

Due to the way it works, introducing NaNs when arguments are not already aligned is pretty much unavoidable.

A better way to join your datasets would be `xarray.concat(..., dim='sample_ID')`. This doesn't try to do anything clever for alignment along the concatenated dimension (`'sample_ID'` in this case), which means it's much faster and preserves integer dtypes.